# second floor walls short?

Tags: wiring, hardwood

Live in the US.  House is from 1972.  I am trying to run some cable from the attic to the basement and the only real path is behind my closet in a room on the second floor.  Need to drill a hole upwards to the attic in the wall. Plus about 12 inches of wood in the closet "floor" to an area that hits the basement. Have a 4.5 foot flexible augur bit.  Want to leave behind an access panel since it's probably an area one day myself or someone will want to get to again for wiring. Panel I'm looking to keep behind is 6 x 12 in.

Anyway, in measuring from floor to ceiling I am measuring 89".  Was originally trying to identify placement based on an 8 foot high wall. House did come with hardwood floors but assuming that is not accounting for 7 inches of height loss.  Am I missing something?

Side item if there are any thoughts.  Assuming I may have a 2x4 to drill thru plus a thin panel in the attic to drill thru?  I found three horizontal items in the floor with a scope and stud finder that as mentioned measures around 12 inches with gaps in between each piece of wood.  What is the usual layout of the "ceiling" in the wall when there is an open attic above it?

--- Here is some more detail as requested ---

So this is the basement and there is a small opening on the shelf going down the stairs.  Blue tape shows the studs and where I want to run wires down to

[image]

Below shows the wall directly above the basement and the red line showing the path for the wires again.  Vertical blue tape shows again the studs here which is basically 12” apart.  The horizontal ones lower on the wall seems to be the floor of the second floor and then what seems like two other horizontal boards.

[image]

Above the arrow above, shows where I ran the scope thru the wall from the basement and then hit wood.  Can see some existing wires that were somehow snaked around that wood not thru it that go to the basement already.

[image]

Then here is the inside of the wall of the closet.  Again red arrow shows the cable running thru the wall and where it would be. Wall is 89” high and seems like I need to get into the wall and dig 12” into the ground plus some amount into the attic.  Below shows the size of the access panel I bought as thinking of not sealing it off in the future and since it’s not noticeable with clothes in the closet.

[image]

Attic view of wires already coming out that area.  Current hole full up.  All I see from the attic side is the drywall and then a think piece of wood that covers the whole top of the closet ceiling in the wall.  Next to it covered by some loose insulation is the drywall.

[image]

Any thoughts on where I should put the access panel considering the augur flexible bit I have?  Other thoughts on the attic area I'm looking at and thoughts on what I saw in the floor area?

Comment: please draw some diagrams

Comment: Raw hight would be 8 feet, the standard length of the 2x4 studs. Minus the hardwood floor and the added ceiling insulation. Yes you will have horizontal framing studs, but. you can drill those.

Comment: You've asked several questions here.  You're more likely to get responses if you separate into distinct posts.

Comment: I've worked on many homes from all 20th century decades and still wouldn't be able to give you any real advice here. There could be all manner of framing, blocking, bracing, etc. in there. The only way forward is to investigate it yourself, as you have been. Open more drywall if necessary. It shouldn't be too difficult to repair what looks like a smooth finish.